# The "zip" translation loader is not registered - Prestashop

Tags: symfony, prestashop-1.7

When I try to access several options of the backend of prestashop 1.7.4.3 it gives me this error. I have installed four languages and the main one is Spanish. How can this error be solved?

[Error 500 - The "zip" translation loader is not registered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3qrX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a zip file in your translations folder. Perhaps it was left there when you installed a new locale. Try removing it.

Comment: Now I have reinstalled prestashop from 0 but it is very good to know if it happened again. Thank you.